# obtain slice of array from first element containing string to last element containing another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get a slice of an array of strings from the first element that contains these letters in this case until the last element containing these letters in this case.

First the input is a sentence, so I split it by whitespace. Then I'm trying to get a slice from the indexOf('IN') until the lastIndexOf('NN'), but am getting an empty array.

Here is what I tried:

```
var str = "weather(NN) in(IN) boston(NN)"
str.split(' ').slice(str.split(' ').indexOf('IN'), str.split(' ').lastIndexOf('NN')+1);
```

How can I get it so that I get `["in(IN)", "boston(NN)"]` or if the string is "weather(NN) in(IN) boston(NN) massachusetts(NN)", I get `["in(IN)", "boston(NN)", "massachusetts(NN)"]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` methods doesn't look for substrings in the array items, they only look for matches of the complete item.

You can use the `reduce` and `reduceRight` methods to seek the array:

```
var str = "weather(NN) in(IN) boston(NN)";

var arr = str.split(' ');
var first = arr.reduce(function(p, c, i){
  return p != -1 ? p : c.indexOf('IN') != -1 ? i : -1;
}, -1);
var last = arr.reduceRight(function(p, c, i, a){
  return p != -1 ? p : c.indexOf('NN') != -1 ? i : -1;
}, -1);    
arr = arr.slice(first, last + 1);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8WS3g/

Note: The `Array.reduce` and `Array.reduceRight` methods are only supported in IE9 and later. (The same goes for the `Array.index` and `Array.indexOf` method used in the question, so it doesn't change the requirements.)

Comment: one last thing. How can I get all the elements containing only (NN) ?

Comment: @user3743069: You can use the `filter` method: `var nn = arr.filter(function(v){ return v.indexOf('(NN)') != -1; });`.

Answer (score 1):

Find the substring that matches your criteria, then split it.  The first part uses regex to search for a string which ends with (IN).  The second part finds the last index of (NN) then adds 4 to account for 4 chars in (NN).

Like this:

```
var str = "weather(NN) in(IN) boston(NN)";
str.substring(str.search(/[^\s]+\(IN\)/), str.lastIndexOf('(NN)') + 4).split(' ')
//["in(IN)", "boston(NN)"]
```

It also works on:

```
var str = "weather(NN) in(IN) boston(NN) is(VBZ)";
//["in(IN)", "boston(NN)"]

var str = "bad(JJ) weather(NN) in(IN) boston(NN) is(VBZ)";
//["in(IN)", "boston(NN)"]
```

Comment: This doesn't look for an item containing `"IN"`, it always takes from the second item. If the string for example is `"bad(XX) weather(NN) in(IN) boston(NN)"` it will return `["weather(NN)", "in(IN)", "boston(NN)"]`.

Comment: wait @Guffa is right. how can I get it to work after `IN` not just the second element.

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood the question.  I updated my response.